# File Not Found - Problem With \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, miktex

I'm having a great deal of difficulty adding figures into a LaTeX template I downloaded. I downloaded and unzipped the template folder to a new folder, and am attemping to integrate a picture called "n1" that is contained in this folder. Unfortunately, I have had nothing but problems and have received file not found innumerable times.

I am using MikTeX 2.9, and I updated the file name database and added the file n1 to all of the folders specific under Setting-Roots. I am able to incorporate the file into other latex documents that I have created myself, but, for a reason I cannot determine, I can't add files to this template that I downloaded.

I am using pdfLaTeX.

Every attempt yields the following:

```
\includegraphics{n1} LaTeX Error: File `n1' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.81 \includegraphics{n1}

?
```

The exact path of n1 is:

```
C:\Users\George\Documents\Thesis\psu-thesis\n1.png
```

The location of the TeX document is:

```
C:\Users\George\Documents\Thesis\psu-thesis\sample.tex
```

IF I state in the pre amble:

```
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/George/Documents/Thesis/psu-thesis/}}
```

I still receive the above error.
I have attempted every solution that was suggested in past threads, and nothing has worked. Refreshing the FNDB was unsuccessful. Adding an absolute path was also unsuccessful. I greatly hope that the brilliant minds here will be able to think of a solution!

EDIT

Hellow world log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2012.1.19)  4 MAY 2015 13:58
entering extended mode
**C:/Users/George/Documents/Thesis/psu-thesis/hello_world.tex
(C:/Users/George/Documents/Thesis/psu-thesis/hello_world.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2009-06-19, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, lao, latin, lat
vian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerm
an, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, 
romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swis
sgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, u
senglishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(C:\Users\George\Documents\Thesis\psu-thesis\hello_world.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 6.
 [1

{C:/Users/George/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(C:\Users\George\Documents\Thesis\psu-thesis\hello_world.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 225 strings out of 494045
 2698 string characters out of 3145966
 48890 words of memory out of 3000000
 3594 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 6675 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 715 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,6n,17p,244b,187s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program File
s (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Program Files (
x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86
)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb>
Output written on hello_world.pdf (1 page, 33459 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 18 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What extension does `n1` have?

Comment: Even brilliant minds needs a minimum of information. Your question is too vage, you give neither a complete example, nor the exact file name of the graphics, nor the pathes you used.

Comment: If you can use the image in other documents but not this one, then the problem is somewhere in the code for this one (probably). So what exactly is in this one? Normally, you don't install images into your TEXMF tree at all. The easiest way is just to have the image file in the same directory as your `.tex` file.

Comment: @egreg, it's just .png.

Comment: Next guess: are you compiling with `latex` or `pdflatex`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I apologize for the vague-ness. I'll append to above post momentarily.

Comment: @egreg, I am compiling with pdflatex, I believe I mentioned this above, but I will add it if I missed it.

Comment: Create a short hello world example in the same folder as your document, compile it as you would do with the sample.tex and show the log-file.

Comment: Did you try to specify the file extension?
`\includegraphics{n1.png}`

Comment: @Carlos Viegas - yes, this does not solve the problem.

Comment: And how about compiling with pdftex, instead of pdflatex?

Comment: @CarlosViegas Lots of other errors arise with using pdflatex, it doesn't recognize the document class.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Let me know if that is what you wanted done, I added it above.

Comment: Hm. Now create a small testinput.tex-file (in the same folder) with the simple content  "Hello" and add \input{testinput} to your hello world file. Is it found?

Comment: Yes the file is found. I also put the \input{testinput} command in the sample.tex file. It was found there as well. \includegraphics{n1} still returns error.

Comment: Just in case: You are sure that your graphic is called n1 and not nl?

Comment: Yes. I also tested creating another image named "bob" in the same folder. Same problem. I apologize if this is something simple, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Try this [man's photo](https://www.joomeo.com/us/help.php?Question=114), for example. Rename it to n1. What is the result?

Comment: Same error, downloaded it to the same folder.

Comment: My last idea, try moving only the `.tex` and `n1.png` files to another location on your drive where you have full priviledges, say `D:\testfolder`. Is it solved?

Comment: Add `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\includegraphics{n1}` to the helloworld.tex and try again.

Comment: And check if your sample.tex contains somewhere an option "dvips". If yes remove it ...

Comment: Removing dvips made it work! Does dvips preclude the use of includegraphics? Submit this as an answer and I will mark it as correct as you have definitely got it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your template passes the option `dvips` to graphicx. But as you are using pdflatex (and not latex + dvips), you are lying to latex and so it doesn't look for the correct graphic type. Remove the option and hope that your template doesn't do more such silly things.

Comment: The unintentional lie did me in! Thanks for helping and thanks for your exception explanation. Much appreciated, I was losing my hair over this.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: How to configure for that? latex + dvips or does it require any other changes?